# How to make sure only one Akka JAR makes it on the classpath?

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I'm running into a `akka.ConfigurationException: Akka JAR version [2.1.0] does not match the provided config version [2.2.3]`. My speculation is that, somehow, `$SCALA_HOME/lib/akka-actors.jar` is making it onto the classpath along with the Akka JAR managed by SBT.

I created a simple standalone SBT project to demonstrate the issue (see below). My $SCALA_HOME points to Scala 2.10.3. In Build.scala I'm explicitly setting `scalaHome` to `$SCALA_HOME`

`project/Build.scala`

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
  val appName     = "akka-version-problem"
  val appVersion  = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

  val getJars = TaskKey[Unit]("get-jars")
  val getJarsTask = getJars <<= (target, fullClasspath in Compile) map { (target, cp) =>
    println(cp map { _.data } filter { _.getAbsolutePath.contains("lib") } mkString "\n")
    println(cp map { _.data } filter { _.getAbsolutePath.contains("akka") } mkString "\n")
  }

  lazy val root = Project("root", file(".")).settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.3",

    scalaHome := Some(file(System.getenv("SCALA_HOME"))),

    autoScalaLibrary := false,

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.3"
    ),

    getJarsTask
  )
}
```

`src/main/scala/com/example/Main.scala`

```
package com.example

import akka.actor.ActorSystem

object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("AkkaDemoSystem")
  system.shutdown()
}
```

When I run `sbt get-jars` I don't see `$SCALA_HOME/lib/akka-actors.jar` in the output
When I run `sbt run` I get:

```
[error] (run-main) 44c2d48a-8899-43f9-804b-55cbf739b08bakka.ConfigurationException: Akka JAR version [2.1.0] does not match the provided config version [2.2.3]
44c2d48a-8899-43f9-804b-55cbf739b08bakka.ConfigurationException: Akka JAR version [2.1.0] does not match the provided config version [2.2.3]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:465)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:93)
    at com.example.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:6)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at com.example.Main$.main(Main.scala:5)
    at com.example.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Am I missing something obvious? Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: Why do you use: "    scalaHome := Some(file(System.getenv("SCALA_HOME")))," ?

Comment: because i'd like to use Scala that is already on the file system, as opposed to letting SBT re-download it...

Comment: Well, it only does it once. I guess my point is that if you had avoided that you'd already be up and running.

Comment: There's little reason to go against the grain and try to micro-manage and / or second guess SBT's operations.

Comment: @ViktorKlang for now i'm up and running without scalaHome

Comment: @RandallSchulz are you suggesting that using [well documented](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Configuring-Scala.html#using-scala-from-a-local-directory) functionality is "going against the grain"?

Comment: In fact, yes. Just 'cause it's available doesn't mean you should use it. There's no reason to force SBT to use a particular installation of Scala when it does very nicely handling that aspect itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that akka-actors.jar is *part* of the scala distribution.  Sbt, by default, includes all these jars on your classpath.  SO, you wind up with the Akka version from the scala distribution *and* the one you depend on directly.

Not only that, you're including scala-actors, scala-reflect, etc.   If this is what you want, great.

If you'd like to prevent yourself from using more jars than you want, you should create the `scalaInstance` you use directly.  See http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/index.html#sbt.ScalaInstance$ for the construction methods (You can see one of these uses the scalaHome).

I'd recommend doing something like (note: sbt 0.13 code):

```
scalaInstance := {
    val homeDir = file("/path/to/scala-home")
    val jars = (homeDir ** ".jar").get
    val notAkka = jars filterNot (_ contains "akka")
    val scalaLib = ScalaInstance.scalaJar(homeDir, "scala-library.jar")
    val compilerLib = ScalaInstance.scalaJar(homeDir, "scala-compiler.jar")
    ScalaInstance(scalaLib, compilerLib, notAkka:_*)(state.classLoaderCache.apply _)
}
```

This will fire you a deprecated warning. This is because we assume that if you're using scalaHome you *want* all those default modules from scala.   Since this isn't the case, you can ignore that.

As Viktor says, I'd recommend just using sbt's resolution mechanism for Scala.  The caching is of classloaders is done by default if you do this, *and* it will only download the artifact once.   The reality is, that sbt has to download a version of scala anyway to compile your build before it knows you've configured a scalaHome for the project (since you specify this using scala itself).

Hope that helps!